# IPython, "name 'plt' not defined"

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, atom-editor, hydrogen

I recently installed Atom as an IDE on my laptop, for university. I installed Hydrogen as a convenient solution to show some plots on the go.
But whenever I run Hydrogen, I get this error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
< ipython-input-1-1eb00ff78cf2>  in <module>

----> 1 plt.show()


NameError: name 'plt' is not defined
```

However Matplotlib is working properly when executed normally, and IPython seems to do as well.
This is the code I'm trying to run test-wise:

```
%matplotlib ipympl

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a_x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
a_y=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

plt.plot(a_x, a_y)
plt.show()
```

A video of the problem is available [here](https://streamable.com/rbsr5).

[image]

- Selected `Run`

[image]

- Resulting error

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- As shown in the OP, `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` is present, but it didn't get executed.

  - You only executed the selected line (9) with `plt.show()`, not the whole file.
- You can see the problem by carefully reading the traceback. `Line 9` in the script is `line 1` in the traceback: `----> 1 plt.show()`
- The solution is to run the whole file, not one line. Click <kbd>Run All</kbd>  not <kbd>Run</kbd>.

Answer (score 30):

You have to import the library first. Add this at start of the code.-

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Comment: _You have to import the library first._ is not correct, and the canonical way to import pyplot is `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, as shown in the [matplotlib User Guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py)